# webfaction hosted django app, shopify module will not import

Tags: django, shopify, webfaction

I've recently created a site with a django app hosted by webfaction. In general, things are running as expected, but I am also trying to use the ShopifyAPI, and get "Import error, no module named shopify" traced to one of my views.py. Everything worked when developing on localhost.

I SSHed into the host server and tried to install the ShopifyAPI with easy_install. It seemed to have reported being successfully installed, but I'm not sure if this actually does anything real on an external server?

Does anybody have suggestions? Any limitations on ShopifyAPI that I may not have considered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy_install command will install the module for Python2.4. You are likely using Python2.6 or Python2.7. If you are using **Python2.6**, enter:

`easy_install-2.6 ShopifyAPI` instead of `easy_install ShopifyAPI`.

If you are using **Python2.7**, enter:

`easy_install-2.7 ShopifyAPI` insead of `easy_install ShopifyAPI`.

You can read more about using easy_install on Webfaction [here](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/python.html#installing-packages-with-easy-install)

After installing the API, restart your Apache instance and it should see the module as expected.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I should mention, my /home/lib/python2.7 didn't exist, so I had to create the directory.